# Adding a Content Add In from a Task pane Add in

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I'm creating a powerpoint add-in with a taskpane add-in. Ideally, when you click on a button on the taskpane, it will insert a content addin on the current active slide.

Is it possible to have a Powerpoint add-in that contains both a content AND taskpane addin? Specifically, is it possible to launch a content addin from a taskpane addin?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest of an Office add-in specifies its type as an attribute of the OfficeApp element. It can be taskpane or content or mail add-in, but not two types at once.

You cannot launch one add-in from another. See the question that Marc linked to in his comment to your question for details.